# Buildroot ".stamp_images_installed" Failed After Folder Name Change

Tags: linux, makefile, u-boot, buildroot

I fire up the Buildroot by **make**. Compilation progress was successful.

In the installation progress, it tried to copy */output/build/uboot/**SPL*** but that folder does not exist. Instead, */output/build/uboot/**spl*** exists.

1. I changed the ***spl*** folder name to ***SPL***
2. Run the **make** again but I got **.stamp_images_installed failed** error. Check the end of the post for full error log.
3. To solve the problem, I want to build the target again so I removed *output/**target*** folder and all the **.stamp_images_installed** files under *output/**build*** but still I got **.stamp_images_installed failed** error.

Why Buildroot still gives me this error ? What am I doing wrong ?

My full error log is as the following;

```
>>> uboot e1cbe8c74e87036e649b0e34656aebabb3aa00c7 Installing to target
>>> uboot e1cbe8c74e87036e649b0e34656aebabb3aa00c7 Installing to images directory
cp -dpf /home/mei/buildroot/output/build/uboot-e1cbe8c74e87036e649b0e34656aebabb3aa00c7/u-boot.bin /home/mei/buildroot/output/images/
cp -dpf /home/mei/buildroot/output/build/uboot-e1cbe8c74e87036e649b0e34656aebabb3aa00c7/u-boot.img /home/mei/buildroot/output/images/
cp -dpf /home/mei/buildroot/output/build/uboot-e1cbe8c74e87036e649b0e34656aebabb3aa00c7/SPL /home/mei/buildroot/output/images/
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/home/mei/buildroot/output/build/uboot-e1cbe8c74e87036e649b0e34656aebabb3aa00c7/SPL'
package/pkg-generic.mk:320: recipe for target '/home/mei/buildroot/output/build/uboot-e1cbe8c74e87036e649b0e34656aebabb3aa00c7/.stamp_images_installed' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/mei/buildroot/output/build/uboot-e1cbe8c74e87036e649b0e34656aebabb3aa00c7/.stamp_images_installed] Error 1
Makefile:84: recipe for target '_all' failed
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *folder* called `spl` (in lowercase), but we're looking for a *file* called `SPL` (in uppercase). When you build a first stage bootloader, it may have various names, depending on the platform. Usually the name is `u-boot-spl.bin`, and it resides inside the `spl` directory. Some platforms, however, use a different name for this file (for historical reasons). For iMX6, the file name is `SPL` and it resides directly in the U-Boot directory.

However, in your case, apparently the `SPL` file doesn't get built. Probably this is because you are using a U-Boot configuration that doesn't build it under that name. If you are actually building for iMX6, this indicates that there is something wrong with your U-Boot configuration. If you're building for some other SoC, it's Buildroot's `BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_SPL_NAME` option that is incorrectly set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I have already handled it by defconfig as you said but I would specifically like to know why I got `stamp` error when I handle it manually, even if all the stamps re-generated manually, and how to solve this problem.

Comment: The 'stamp' error is because Buildroot is based on Makefiles, and the error happens within the make target of a stamp file. The actual error is the line above: `cp: -r not specified; omitting directory`.